# How can I generate sequence number by company

Tags: sequence, odoo-8

I would add a sequence number for employee's contract,

I work with multi company configuration,
How can i specify the sequence number for employee's contract for each company?

(the sequence should be by company)
I try with :

```
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <!--Sequence Type-->
        <record id="ir_seq_type_contract_ref" model="ir.sequence.type">
            <field name="name">Contrat Employe</field>
            <field name="code">hr.contract.ref</field>
        </record>
        <!--Sequence-->
        <record id="ir_seq_contract_ref" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Contrat Employe</field>
            <field name="code">hr.contract.ref</field>
            <field name="prefix">Contrat N°</field>
            <field name="padding">4</field>
            <field name="number_increment">1</field>
            <field name="number_next_actual">1</field>
            <field name="implementation">standard</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

but the sequence is unique for all company

Thank you!

Comment: You question isn't clear. What are you trying to ask? The more relevant data you add, the easier it is for people to answer. Most important: some code snippets :-)

Comment: I would specify the sequence number by company in multi-company configuration odoo

Comment: Not sure you can do this, conceptually (w/o knowing OpenERP all too closely). You need one sequence per company to make this fly, which must be supported specifically by odoo.

Comment: I find solution:
I create scheduler action for create a sequence for all company in the base
and in override of the method create of hr_contract, i choose the ir.sequence object specify for the employee's company (employee_id.company_id)